# Translate string - Magento

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, inline-translations

I need to translate this string into Italian (Please refer to the first image).

I've tried editing the it_IT.csv file in `app/i18n/antoniocarboni/` (as you can see in the second image).

I also deployed the static content but it does not work as I want?

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This phrase contains variables, that will be replaced during phrase rendering.

Use this phrase in your dictionary

> Minimum of different classes of characters in password is %1. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters.

Comment: Already there is this string and also translated but is not taken

Comment: are you use "%1" instead of "3"? are other phrases from your dictionary translated correctly?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean? 
I uploaded another image